# One function to load varrious php pages with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following code that i need some help with, i am trying achieve the same thing with jQuery. I have found some solutions that come close but as yet i am still searching for the perfect solution.

```
function getData(dataSource, divID)
    {
if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
}
}
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
}

}
```

Right now i am triggering the function with:

`<input type = "button" value = "TEST" onclick = "getData('subject_selectAJAX.php?course_id=1', 'ajax')"`>

I would like to achieve the same thing with jQuery. I think the following function although wrong gets close, my problem is that the url changes depending on where the user is within the course. course_select.php is initially loaded into the #ajax div, which then would be replaced with subject_select.php?course_id="*whatever*" followed by topic_select.php?subject_id="*whatever*"

```
function getData() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    $.ajax({
        url: "something.php", //i want this to be passed to the function 
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #ajax div
            $('#ajax').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#ajax').fadeIn('slow');       
        }
```

});
}

I would love some help with this, i'm currently getting confused pretty sure it is something that would help other Ajax jQuery newbies.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work although i'm sure it could be much cleaner and i would still like to add some sort of loading graphic for slower connections.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getData( url, id ){
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          data: "id=" + id,
    cache: false,
          success: function(html){
                     $('#ajax').hide();

                    //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
                    $('#ajax').html(html);

                    //display the body with fadeIn transition
                    $('#ajax').fadeIn('fast');



        })

};

</script>
```